# Removing blank pages when printing - using visibility: hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have a page which displays many posts and allows the printing of a single post (a `div` with all its children).

With clicking on the print button, I go through every element on the page and style it as follows:

- The div to print is set to the class `printme` which styles the `top` and `left` properties to 0 and sets `position` to `absolute`.
- The div to print's children are left alone
- If the element is a parent of the div to print, I add the class `print-visibility-hide` which sets `visibility: hidden`.
- Otherwise, I add a class which sets `display: none`. The output of this is shown below.

Everything works fine except that a blank page prints - which I am presuming is due to the parent divs using `visibility: hidden` to hide content and therefore still taking up space.

Is there any way to print my div and somehow remove or collapse this extra space?

**HTML** - I end up with something like the following (with all the content removed for conciseness):

```
<body class="print-visibility-hide">
  <div class="page-container print-visibility-hide">
    <div class="main print-visibility-hide">
      <div class="main-content d-section-top print-visibility-hide" id="main-content" style="background: transparent none repeat scroll 0% 0%; margin-left: 145px;">
        <div id="gemwrapper" class="gemwrapper print-visibility-hide" style="display: block;">
          <div class="gem-content-wrapper d-item d-section print-visibility-hide">
            <div class="gem-content-main gems print-visibility-hide">
              <div class="print-visibility-hide">
                <div style="display: block;" id="s-g1353" class="print-visibility-hide">
                  <table class="print-visibility-hide">
                    <tbody class="print-visibility-hide">
                      <tr class="item tools print-visibility-hide">
                        <td class="textarea print-visibility-hide">
                          <div id="gparent1353" class="textarea print-visibility-hide">
                            <div id="gx1353" class="printme">
                              <pre>
This is the text I am printing which can be any length.</pre>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  html,
  body {
    height: auto;
  }
  .print-display-none,
  .print-display-none * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .print-visibility-hide,
  .print-visibility-hide * {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
  .printme,
  .printme * {
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  .printme {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .printme,
  .printme:last-child {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use @media Print Like This :

```
@media print {
     html, body {
        border: 1px solid white;
        height: 99%;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        page-break-before: avoid;
     }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Use This Code : Instead Of Your Code

```
@media print {
  html, body {
     border: 1px solid white;
     height: 99%;
     page-break-after: avoid !important;
     page-break-before: avoid !important;
  }
  .print-display-none,
  .print-display-none * {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .print-visibility-hide,
  .print-visibility-hide * {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
  .printme,
  .printme * {
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
  .printme {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: I replaced my  html, body {} with yours, but still am getting 2 pages.

Comment: Have You Tried To use !important After page-break-after: avoid !important; & page-break-before: avoid !important;  Like This

Comment: Yes, still getting 2 pages.

Comment: I don't try.. but remove .printme,
  .printme:last-child {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. Still 2 pages.

Comment: Check Update 2 Code.. This Might Be Helpful.

Comment: I completely swapped out my `@media print {}` for yours, but still 2 pages. I added `background: green` to `.printme{}` and `background: blue` to the `html, body{} `. Only a small single paragraph is printing in green. The rest of the two pages prints blue.

Comment: I had a conflicting html height: 100% definition which was overriding what was set in `@media{}` In the end, `height: auto` or your `height: 99%` both worked once putting `!important` after the height definition. Thanks for your help.